# Lazy- and want all my public members instantiated in constructor

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor

I have a C# class that has dozens of members that are all of the same type, and I always want them to be new'd and not null when the class is instantiated.  So in my class field declarations I write:

```
public ApiParameter mnBatchNumber = new ApiParameter();
public ApiParameter szBatchType = new ApiParameter();
public ApiParameter jdBatchDate = new ApiParameter();
...// and so on, many many times
```

The problem with this is that the part "= new ApiParameter();" is, in my opinion, verbose noise.  Is there a good way that I can cause these fields to always be new'd up when I create the class?  I am thinking that using reflection in the constructor would do this nicely - especially if implemented in my base class.  Does anyone know off the cuff how best to do this?

Comment: Public fields? You are indeed being pretty lazy...

Comment: Have you considered using Arrays? That way, you can use a loop in the constructor. Maybe use '#define' to 'mask' the name. Mind though, that defines can be rather treacherous.

Comment: Probably I don't get you. Why don't you initialize these fields in the constructor of your class?

Comment: @ATaylor But then you lose static information (the name).

Comment: @pst The name can be 'kept' by specifying '#define Name Array[x]'. But I understand what you mean. I just think, that's the quickest way to go about it in a constructor.

Comment: Noise is code thats not needed for some reason.  Theres no noise in what you posted, if you want the members to be initialized you need that code.   The only problem is that you shouldn't be using public fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some reflection that you could use in your constructor:

```
FieldInfo[] fields = this.GetType().GetFields(); //if you're using private fields use GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic)
foreach(FieldInfo f in fields){
     if(f.FieldType == typeof(ApiParameter)){
        f.SetValue(this, new ApiParameter());
     }
}
```

Comment: Is this what you was asking for?

Answer (score 1):

Don't see any *bad* coding style here apart a fact which mantioned by @Marc: do not use public field, if don't have really good reasons for that.

If *really* don't like intializing members on top of the file, may be, you can initilize them in `static constructor`, but I repeat, I would prefer the way you already did, but on *private* fields.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution, based on using Expression Tree.
Advantage of this solution is that slow reflection mechanism is used only once, when first instance of your type is created.

```
//public fields are of this type
public class TestClass
{

}
//Class with public fields
public class TestContainerClass
{
    public TestClass TestClassField1;
    public TestClass TestClassField2;
    public TestClass TestClassField3;
    public TestClass TestClassField4;
    //should fill this list on creation of first instance and then use it
    //assume that type is not changed in a runtime
    private static List<Action<TestContainerClass,TestClass>> _fieldInitializers;

    public TestContainerClass()
    {
        if (_fieldInitializers == null)
        {
            _fieldInitializers = new List<Action<TestContainerClass, TestClass>>();
            //use reflection only once
            FieldInfo[] testClassFieldInfos =
                this.GetType().GetFields().Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof (TestClass)).ToArray();

            foreach (var testClassFieldInfo in testClassFieldInfos)
            {
                //get action to set current field and store it in a list
                var fieldSetter = GetFieldAssigner<TestContainerClass, TestClass>(testClassFieldInfo);
                _fieldInitializers.Add(fieldSetter);
            }
        }
        //next lines will set all 
        foreach (var fieldInitializer in _fieldInitializers)
        {
            fieldInitializer(this,new TestClass());
        }
    }

    public static Action<T, I> GetFieldAssigner<T, I>(FieldInfo fieldInfo)
    {
        ParameterExpression targetExp =
        Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "target");

        ParameterExpression valueExp =
        Expression.Parameter(typeof(I), "value");

        MemberExpression fieldExp = Expression.Field(targetExp, fieldInfo);
        BinaryExpression assignExp = Expression.Assign(fieldExp, valueExp);


        var setter = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, I>>(assignExp, targetExp, valueExp).Compile();
        return setter;
    }
}
```

Also, I would like to notice that when you combine initialization and declaration of your fields, you may find your constructors a bit bloated like this:

```
class SomeType
{
    private int _x = 12;//declare and init

    public SomeType()
    { 
       _x = 12;//compiler inserted that line
    }

    public SomeType(BlahBlahType blahBlahObject)
    {
        _x = 12;//compiler inserted that line
    }
    //other constructors will also have _x = 12; line 
}
```